# What problems might the following macro bring to the application?

Tags: c++, c, macros

Can the following macro bring problems?

```
#define sq(x) x*x
```

If yes, then how and why?please help.

Comment: Side effects! You need extra `(`,`)`.

Comment: What have you tried?  What does your text book suggest?  What did your course tutor suggest in his lecture?

Comment: It was an open ended question type.just gave this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it can present problems. Other than the obvious fact that macros don't respect namespaces at all (which means you can't call anything else `sq`), try the following:

```
int result = sq(4) / sq(4);
```

You should surround `x * x` with parenthesis so it becomes `((x) * (x))`.

Another problem:

```
int a = 0;
int result = sq(++a);
```

This is an inherent problem with macros, and is one reason inline functions should be preferred.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not going to give you a straight answer (this looks like a homework question), but I'm going to give you an example that will hopefully make you think about it and come up with a correct answer:

```
#include <iostream>

#define sq_macro(x) x * x

int sq_function(int x)
{
    return x * x;
}

int print_and_ret(int x)
{
    std::cout << x << '\n';
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Calling sq_macro:\n";
    sq_macro(print_and_ret(10));

    std::cout << "Calling sq_function:\n";
    sq_function(print_and_ret(10));
}
```

When you run the program, the macro and the function give two different behaviors. Think about what a macro is, and what a function is.

Comment: Too many people after the low hanging fruit - +1 for trying to make him think ;)

Comment: @Caribou Yeah, by the time one hits the button, there's already a flood of answers, heh.

Answer (score 3):

While writing macros use brackets excessively. Rewrite the macro as follows

```
#define sq(x) ((x)*(x))
```

If you don't do this then you will have problems in cases where macro is used as `sq(5+4)`

To understand the problem do macro expansion and see.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out, you should wrap each use of the argument in parentheses to ensure correct behavior, for example, when the argument is something like `i * 2`:

```
#define sq(x) ((x)*(x))
```

But there is another potential issue. Consider the following:

```
result = sq(++i);
```

This is translated to:

```
result = ((++i)*(++i))
```

Where as the intention was likely to increment `i` only once, it gets incremented twice. This is a common side effect for macros.

One approach is just to be aware of this when calling it, but a better one is to put `sq()` in its own inline function.

Answer (score 1):

All of these can cause trouble:

```
int x = 12;
int n = sq(x+3);
int y = sq(x++);
int z = 2 * sq(2 + n) * n;
```

comparared with a function `sq`.

Answer (score 1):

For one, operator precedence would be messed  up:

```
sq(2+2); // author wants 4*4, but gets 2+2*2+2.
```